# changePage to call method in target page java script file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am using the following code to changePage  from First.html

```
$.mobile.changePage("Second.html", { transition: "slide" });
```

But this is neither calling document.ready on Second.js or pageshow or pagecreate events.

How do I call a method in Second.js after Second.html is loaded?

Comment: what version of jquery are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess your problem is related to placement of your **Second.js** file.

When loading intermediate pages, jQuery Mobile will strip whole page and load only **BODY** content. This is because jQuery Mobile uses **AJAX** for page handling. Only first (initial) page is fully loaded into the **DOM**. For other pages it is not necessary to load everything, no point if you already have whole page loaded into the **DOM**.

Read [**this**](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/) article to find more about this problem. You will find several working solution.